# Are there pointerout-like events when hitting Chrome breakpoints?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, browser

I have a browser program that performs certain actions if a mouse button is held down. To accomplish this, the program listens for `pointerdown` and `pointerup` events on the `document` object. When receiving these events, the program sets (or unsets) some flags that track button-held state. There are a number of other input events that should also unset a button-held flag, like `focusout` and `pointerout`.

Browser breakpoints seem to be a grey area. In Firefox, holding the mouse down and triggering a breakpoint causes the `pointerout` event to get fired, which lets me properly unset button-held flags. However, Chrome (87.0.4280.88, Mac OS) does not appear to fire any of `blur`, `pointerout`, `mouseout`, or `focusout` when hitting a breakpoint. The result is that after I've resumed normal execution, my program code still thinks a mouse button is held down until I click again in the browser window.

Is there a workaround for this? There doesn't appear to be any way to directly poll the state of the mouse, so it seems I need to rely completely on events to drive this.